# How to add a pattern in arabic characters or digits inibm watson assistant to be recognized as entity

Tags: regex, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to add an entity to be detected when there are 3 subsequent arabic characters followed by 3 arabic digits in IBM watson assistant. I have adjusted the settings of the chatbot to be in arabic since the chatbot is in the arabic language, however, when I add a pattern such as \u0660-\u0669 it gives me an error and it is not written like that, it is written in arabic digits \u٠٦٦٠-\u٠٦٦٩ and this and so it is not recognized.